# BI SSRS and Visual Studio compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have :

Visual Studio 2012 / Visual Studio 2013 installed

and

SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2/ SQL server 2012 installed

I will create a new BI/SSRS project (I'm a beginner ).

Which version of BI/SSRS should I install ?

And which "couple" of installation (VS version/ SQL server version)is better to work with ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Is Report Builder 3.0 an option? You can use the version to match your version of SSRS then. (So Report Builder 3.0 2012 to match SSRS 2012 to match SQL Server 2012.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have reports built with prior versions of VS, you can usually open them in the newest version and it will upgrade them. Once upgraded, however, you usually can't open them in a prior version of VS.

The VS version has very little to do with the SQL version, so any combo is fine. I'd recommend using VS 2013, the most recent version you have, unless you can't or don't want to update existing reports.

VS gives you more flexibility than Report Builder, but has more of a learning curve.